# Plot coloured region X axis in PyQtgrpah

Tags: colors, pyqt5, pyqtgraph, region, x-axis

I need to plot a graph in PyQt5 with PyQtgraph with custom plot like this in QtChart:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bdlvx.png)

Linkt to the cutom QtChart example: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcharts-customchart-example.html#running-the-example

I think in QtChart/C++ is pretty clear how to do it in the link above. But I haven't found anything in the documentation to do this in pyqtgraph.

Could anyone give me a hint in a documentation or simple example, please? Or maybe can't do this in pyqtgraph.

Thanks a lot.